# CardsUI - Delete a row from database on the OnDismissCallback

Tags: android, android-view

**PRELUDE**

I'm building a Fragment using the [CardsUI](https://bitbucket.org/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android) from Nadav Fima. 
There is a List< Weight > that I iterate to fill the cardsview with cards:

```
list = wom.getWeights();
    if (list != null) {
        for (Weight w : list) {
            cardsview.addCard(new WeightCard(w), true);
        }
    }
```

Weight has long id; double weight; int quantity; as variables with respective get/set methods. 
I use this class to build the DB using stORM, so there is a database from where (using wom.getWeights()) I get a the List< Weight >.

This is the WeightCard class:

```
public class WeightCard extends Card {

private Weight weight;

public WeightCard(Weight w) {
    this.weight = w;
}

@Override
public View getCardContent(Context context) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.weight_card,
            null);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvWeight)).setText(""
            + Double.toString(weight.getWeight()));
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity)).setText(""
            + Integer.toString(weight.getQuantity()));

    return view;
}

}
```

**PROBLEM**

I want to use a swipe to cancel one of the weights from the list. To do that I use the callback OnDismissCallback from the library.
BUT, I don't know how to get the id of the Weight that back the card.

I know I should use the onDismiss(View v, Object token) method, but I can't figure out how.